# How to consolidate dates in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, consolidation

I have two columns. One with the dates, and other with the counts. 
It looks like this:

```
Stamp:.................... Views
13-12-2013 9:00.... 2
13-12-2013 9:00.... 8 
13-12-2013 10:00... 4
14-12-2013 10:00... 4
14-12-2013 10:00... 11
```

When I consolidate this, I get weird values like this:

```
2
41621,375   8
41621,41667 4
41622,41667 11
```

It seems that Excel is calculating the dates. I would like to prevent that. I searched the whole internet for any solutions, but found no final
answer.

Suggestions?

Comment: Its because the cells are not formatted to show date or time. Change the format to date and time for these cells.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just formatted it to dd-mm-yy hh:mm, but I still get weird values when I'm consolidating the cells. So I guess this is not the right way to solve it.

Comment: Define "consolidating". What operations are involved exaclty?

Comment: The same method as explained here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/use-consolidate-to-summarize-excel-data-without-sorting/6521/
On strings it works fine, it consolidate well. But it runs into werid values, when I consolidate dates and time.

Comment: What values are "weird"? Those like "41621,375"?

Comment: Indeed, then I get values like 41621,375.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got consolidate to work on data with dates. But I needed to make a new tab with formulas that refer to the original tab. So I would start by making a new tab with the headings of:

1. Stamp (text)
2. Views

Then, under the Views heading, add a formula (in B2) referencing the data in the original tab's B2:

```
    ='<original tab name>'!B2
```

Then drag that formula down as far as you need to so all the data is present. Then, under the Stamp (text) heading, add a formula (in A2) to convert the date data to text:

```
    =TEXT('<original tab name'!A2,"dd-mm-yyyy H:MM")
```

Once again, drag that formula down as far as you need to so all the data is present. Then consolidate on the new tab. I did the following:

1. Click on D1
2. Click Consolidate
3. Select A1:B6 (all the data including headers)
4. Make sure Top row and Left column are checked
5. Click OK

The correct consolidated data is inserted at D1.

I used [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) as a reference for how to use the text formula.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to hear it! No problem :)