# Date range summing up in consolidation

Tags: excel

I have searched for help on how to get consolidation in excel not to sum dates. Ive found a similar question answered [How to consolidate dates in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403986/how-to-consolidate-dates-in-excel)
I have tried creating a new tab for formulas and then consolidate again but dnt seem to work. I need consolidation to read my client billing dates as is and not sum it e.g billing date: 2016/09/01 and not 2250/02/20. please help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your post with some sample data, screenshots, the desired outcome and elaborate a bit more what you mean by `...but dnt seem to work`. Is there an error coming up? Is the outcome not what you expected? Why so? etc... That will help us better understand the problem and help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest bet will be to do this via PivotTables.

Click inside your data table.
From the Ribbon, choose Insert > PivotTable.  Make sure the selection includes all of your data. 
Drag your date column into the Row Labels area.
Drag your various other columns into either the Column labels or Values area, depending on what you want.
Click within your long list of dates and choose from the ribbon: PivotTable Tools > Group Selection and choose by day, week, month, year, etc.